# Query without dependencies recursive table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select a database registry that does not have dependencies (look at the figure and the result).

[image: TABLE]

RESULT

[image: RESULTADO]

I have tried with the following function:

```
create or replace function consultar(id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(cod character varying, nom character varying) as
$$
declare
ids character varying[];
begin
ids:=(select array(select distinct tb_plan_p from 
tb_plan where 
tb_plan_p is not null order by tb_plane_p));

RETURN QUERY
select tb_plan_cod, tb_plan_des
from tb_plan
where tb_plan_cod <> any(ids) order by tb_plane_cod;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried first to create an array that contains the cod that have dependencies and then remove those cod from the result
But I have not got what I want

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally certain that I understood the requirement correctly, but it seems to me that you are looking for this query:

```
SELECT cod, name
FROM tb_plan AS p1
WHERE fk IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM tb_plan AS p2
         WHERE p2.fk = p1.cod
      );
```